# saving textformat when extracting pdf content

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am currently trying to replace certain words, in an existing pdf that has certain formatting[like tables and stuff]. I have successfully replaced the words by extracting the words utilizing ITextSharp /c# and saving into a string. Afterword, applying replace operation using a regex. When I save this result to pdf file the formatting of the original is not saved.

I have tried uploading to Google drive and convert the file to doc but the format gets messed up. I was thinking of using Acarbat SDK but the current version installed seems messed up and wont let me run javascript

Long story short: I was wondering if Itextsharp has feature to extract format of document like a css file OR  is there a better way to do this operation.

Comment: You can extract more information from a PDF but there are certain information missing for actual editing like start and end of paragraphs, margins, column borders, table cell borders, ... PDF simply is not a format meant for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the examples for iText (http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-15) for modifying the page content and structure? The examples are in Java, but it should be relatively straightforward to convert to C#.

Since your document is formatted like a table, this sounds like the most promising approach, since changing text should not shift other text on the page.